# Javascripts stop working after AJAX page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete, history.js

The basic problem is this...

My site is set up like so :

```
<player> // A fixed div that contains JPlayer and it's playlist
<main> // all content in here is ajaxed including the links to mp3's for the player
```

Basically everything works just fine until you click a link which loads a new page at which point JPlayer refuses to load anymore songs and JQuery autocomplete (in the search box) stops working.

Could you please take a look at the site and see if you can tell what's causing the scripts to fail after an Ajax load?

To see the problem in action :

1) click this link - http://bit.ly/ajaxtest

2) click on the play button on any of the tracks on the page

3) once the song is playing click on an album cover in the "Most Popular Releases" section

4) The new page will load, Jplayer will continue to play uninterrupted but the play links & autocomplete on then new page will no longer work unless you hit the refresh button which just reloads the whole site (which is obviously not what I'm aiming for by ajaxing the thing in the first place).

Many thanks in advance,

G ;)

Comment: in chrome console I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined global.js:371` (btw this is not a question but a request to debug your code)

Comment: Thanks, missed that one! Fixed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the DOM fragment of the old 'page' you also remove any event handlers bound to   elements inside it.

There are 2 options to handle this:

1. delegate your event handlers so that they survive the page change; in jQuery this would look like `$(document).on('click', '.play', ...)` instead of `$('.play').on('click', ...)`
2. or, you can rebind the events to the new 'page' after it is inserted i.e. run your event binding set-up and initialise plugins again after the ajax call completes and the new 'page' is in the DOM

Comment: Thanks @thefrontender, this worked :

    `$(document).on('click', '.load_tk', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  myPlaylist.add({
    etc etc etc...`

But now only the play links located in the actual tracklist are working. The play links in the Top 10 section no longer work at all. Both are using the same class to send the data to the player so can you think why one set would be working and the other not?

Comment: It's ok I found it.. No idea how this was working before but I hadn't included a href in the Top 10 list links.. All working now, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ahhh autocomplete is still not working though. Any thoughts on how to get that working on the ajaxed pages?

Comment: You need to re-initialise the autocomplete plugin after the new page is inserted.